# jQuery call function from external JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, external

I want to call a function from my master .js file - from within my php page. Is this possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   functionName(); //calling function from master.js file
</script>
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Should work. Did you load `master.js` before this script?

Comment: you need to include master.js before the line you call the funcion inside master.js

Comment: Yep I checked, can't figure it out.

Comment: Try to type in master.js : "alert(1)" then check if the alertbox is shown ?

Answer (score 1):

It should be as long as the external script is loaded first and "functionName()" is attached to the global scope

Comment: It seems to call it when it's not within the dom ready handler

Comment: when the master.js is not in the dom ready handler? or when call in your questin is not in the dom ready handler

Comment: when the function i'm trying to call is outside the dom ready handler it seems to call the function, although when it's inside, it fails.

Comment: Right this makes sense since the call is not in the dom ready handler it will fire off first since getting the dom ready takes a little while. Try putting the function call in the dom ready handler as well

Comment: I can't I'm afraid I'm trying to pass a jQuery function through the main php file because I want to use the $_GET[]; query to trigger the function.

Comment: In that case the only other thing I can recommend is to put your script tag at the bottom of your html file. This will cause the script tag to get rendered AFTER all of the html has been loaded. However this does not guarantee the script tag to render after all images are loaded. So if you have a lot of images on your page the dom ready handler may still fire after this script tag since this waits until the dom is loaded AND the images have loaded to fire